Why GetCellValue of GuiGridView isn't getting the value?
Working on a .vbs automation for SAP and I'm having some issues using a While statement loop. I am attempting to count the amount of specific instances that a certain string occurs in a column.
...
Set Table = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
i = 0
r = 0
p = 0
rowCNT = Table.RowCount
While rowCNT > i
getval = Table.getcellvalue(i, "BWART")
If getval = "value1" Then
    r = r + 1
End If
If getval = "value2" Then
    r = r + 1
End If
If getval = "value3" Then
    p = p + 1
End If
If getval = "value4" Then
    p = p + 1
End If
If getval = "value5" Then
    p = p + 1
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
MsgBox "Recieved:" & r & " & " & "Pulled:" & p ", vbExclamation, "SAP Report"

On the code run attempt, the script displays some unrelated value in the r variable, and no value in the p variable.

The backend doesn't send all the rows to the frontend. Does this answer your question? Can't read all rows from GuiGridView. Getting blank after 34 rows

Would also recommend switching to a For statement instead of a While as you have the Table.RowCount and maybe use InStr() to compare anywhere in the string rather than an exact match.
